# Will remove be called before the put method in the Shared preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to figure out if the method remove(String name) really execute before put.

For example, with the follow code:

```
//String
String newString = "This is a string";
editor.putString("newString", newString);
editor.remove("newString");
editor.commit();
```

The key newString won't appears in the Shared Preferences, but with the follow code:

```
//String
String newString = "This is a string";
editor.putString("newString", newString);
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

The key newString will appears in the Shared preferences.

Can anyone give me an example in which shows that the method remove will be execute before the put method?

Comment: From the android docs, it say 'Note that when committing back to the preferences, all removals are done first, regardless of whether you called remove before or after put methods on this editor.'

Comment: Thanks. And there is where my question comes from. The code doesn't do what the guide says...